Changing default python Version
In Terminal I am getting different python version when i enter

/usr/local/bin/python3
python

I followed the steps given in the image then it works but when I quit the terminal again do the above the above steps then again i get different versions
Write alias in bash_profile
vi ~/.bash_profile  
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3'

Reload bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile


What's the question here? You have different Pythons. which python to figure out what exactly is being run with  python.

where python is shows the old version running when I want to update it to newest as newest is usr/local/bin/python3 it is not happening

I don't think where python shows the old version running. What does it show?
